# PHP Excel reader image/file not found when trying to insert an image into an excel file

Tags: cakephp, phpexcel

I am trying to export an excel sheet/file. Inside the file are product data and I am trying to insert the products' image along with other product data for each product. However everytime I run my export code I get an error which is something like, `File http://path_to_file/image.jpg not found!`. I am using `CakePHP` by the way. My code for exporting the excel sheet goes like this:

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Water_Level');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Water_Level');
$objDrawing->setPath(''.PATH_TO_IMAGES.'image.jpg');
$objDrawing->setHeight(20);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($excel->getActiveSheet());
```

Is there something wrong with my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the argument for `PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing::setPath()` is ment to be a local filesystem path, not a URL.

Comment: Don't know why you got downvoted for a correct answer, but you're right: setPath() must be a local filesystem path, not a url. If necessary, OP should use file_get_contents() or similar to pull the file to a temporary file on the local filesystem, when it can then be inserted as a PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing into PHPExcel using setPath() and deleted once the spreadsheet has been saved